# Elasticsearch: Auto Indices Deletion/Expiry

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, logstash

I want to configure my elasticsearch 0.19.11 to delete indexes every 60s. My elasticsearch config has these 3 lines:

```
node.name: "Saurajeet"
index.ttl.disable_purge: false
index.ttl.interval: 60s
indices.ttl.interval: 60s
```

And its not working
I have 2 default docs indexed. And would be expecting it to go after 60s

```
$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/twitter/_settings?pretty=true
{
  "twitter" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index.version.created" : "191199",
      "index.number_of_replicas" : "1",
      "index.number_of_shards" : "5"
    }
}
```

Also if i m trying to do the following it doesnot have any effect

```
$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/twitter/_settings -d '
> { "twitter": {
>     "settings" : {
>       "index.ttl.interval": "60s"
>    }
>  }
> }
> '
{"ok":true}~/bin/elasticsearc
$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/twitter/_settings?pretty=true
{
  "twitter" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index.version.created" : "191199",
      "index.number_of_replicas" : "1",
      "index.number_of_shards" : "5"
    }
  }
}
```

I have indexes 2 documents and its still showing up after 1hr

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1' -d '
{ 
    "user": "kimchy", 
    "postDate": "2009-11-15T13:12:00", 
    "message": "Trying out Elastic Search, so far so good?" 
}'
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/2' -d '
{ 
    "user": "kimchy", 
    "postDate": "2009-11-15T13:12:00", 
    "message": "Trying out Elastic Search, so far so good?" 
}'
```

**WHAT DID I DO WRONG**

P.S. I want to deploy this config with logstash. So any other alternative can be suggested.
for scaling reasons i dont want this autopurge to be a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Figured out myself. Upgraded elasticsearch version to 1.2.0. You can put in TTLs from the [Mapping API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html).  -> [Put Mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) -> [TTL](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html).

Enabling TTL on type level on an index

```
$ curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/abc/a/_mapping -d '
{
    "a": {
      "_ttl": {
        "enabled": true,
        "default": "10000ms"
      }
    }
}'

$ curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/abc/a/a1 -d '{"test": "true"}'
$ $ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/abc/a/a1?pretty
{
  "_index" : "abc",
  "_type" : "a",
  "_id" : "a1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source":{"test": "true"}
}
$ # After 10s
$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/abc/a/a1?pretty
{
  "_index" : "abc",
  "_type" : "a",
  "_id" : "a1",
  "found" : false
}
```

Note:

- Mapping applies to docs created after creation of mapping.
- Also mapping was created for type a. So if you post to type b and
  expect it expired on TTL, thats not gonna happen.

If you need to expire index, you can also create index level mappings during the [create index](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html) to precreate indexes from your application logic.

Answer (score 8):

I believe the indices.ttl.interval setting is only to tweak the cleanup process timing.

You would need to set the _ttl field for the index/type in order to expire it. It looks like this:

```
{
    "tweet" : {
        "_ttl" : { "enabled" : true, "default" : "60s" }
    }
}
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/ttl-field/